# Oracle save updated rows in log

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an update in my stored procedure. I would like to, save in my log the number of rows updated. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use the sql%rowcount which will return the number of rows Inserted or Updated by the last DML, depending upon how you are calling the procedure , the procedure can return the value as and OUT parameter and your calling program can write into a log file..

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
declare
    l_rows_updated number;
begin
    update table1 set col1 = 'abc' where foo = 'bar';

    l_rows_updated := sql%rowcount;

    insert into audit_table ( num_rows) values ( l_rows_updated );
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sql%rowcount which will return the number of rows Inserted or Updated by the last DML.
Depending upon how you are calling the procedure, the procedure can return the value as and OUT parameter and your calling program (could be Java, Python ) can write into a log file in the server.